# javascript/jQuery call a function _after_ event has been completed and returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to call a function to check the value of a form input box *after* the keyDown event and all its corresponding callback handlers have finished and returned. I know I need this because if I place a timer in the callback handler which checks the value of the input box after 200 ms or so the value is as expected, but if I check the value at the end of the callback handler itself, its empty.

```
// case 1
$('textbox').keyDown(function(){
  ...
  console.log($(this).val());   // empty, not as expected
});

// case 2
$('textbox').keyDown(function(){
  ...
  var $textbox = $(this);
  var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log($textbox.val());    // works as expected
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }, 200);
});
```

So, is there a clean way in javascript/jQuery to call a function *after* an event has completely finished?

(And yes, I'm aware of the onChange event, but I've tried it and it doesn't work for this scenario. I'm trying to detect user-defined key combinations and this is a corner case. And in this corner case, the keyPress and keyUp events don't fire either, just keyDown.)

Comment: Why don't you show the code you have tried?

Comment: What I see is that the problem you are trying to solve (yeah the Alt+U escenario) is not viable in FF because that interaction is interrupted by the OS. I mean, pressing the alt button is posible to listen, but when you combine it with the 'u' key, it looks like the browser is totally interrupted by the system. But in Chrome, you can get this key combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keyUp`, instead.  `keyDown` is fired before input; `keyUp` is fired after.

Comment: Looks like you added in a restriciton on `keyUp`.  If that is the case, there is no "clean" way to do this.  In order to allow the event to complete firing, you need JavaScript to terminate the `keyDown` handler completely.  Therefore, your only option, if you truly cannot listen on a appropriate event, is something like `setTimeout`.

Comment: I've edited my question to show that keyPress and keyUp don't fire in this particular scenario. Its to catch when someone enters `Alt+U` on a Mac in Firefox, which results in some special accent characters

Comment: Have you tried binding `keyUp` or `keyPress` to `window`, instead?

Comment: Yup, tried binding to `window` and was surprised they didn't fire. Seems like those events are "eaten up" by the browser at a lower level when this sequence is entered.

Comment: I don't like this suggestion at all, but if this is very much a corner case for a specific keystroke (and it sounds like a bug), you could write the event listeners for `keyUp`, then also add a listener for `keyDown`.  In that listener, if the keystroke is the problematic one, you could then manually invoke `keyUp`.  This will get messy; you'll have to suppress some events, too.  Also: might want to try binding `keyUp` to `document`, too.

Comment: `document` doesn't work either. I guess I should make it clear that the problem is not so much that keyPress/keyUp aren't firing, rather that only a _single_ keyDown event is fired, which itself only contains the `Alt` key keyCode - so I have no idea that a `U` was pressed after that. Hence why I'm resorting to the value of the textbox as a last resort.

Comment: Take a look at the approach applied here.  http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/shift_mode.php

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend Try this you will get it

```
$('textbox').keyDown(function(e){
  ...
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which));   
});
```

This show the key you have pressed.

Hope this solves your problem